# What is Bluetooth maximum bandwidth?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm doing a research about Bluetooth and I'm not sure what is the bluetooth maximum bandwidth?
I've seen that bandwidth is measured by Mbps and I've only seen Mhz... Help please

Comment: It might be a good idea to actually do some research. You're not going to get far by posting questions that are literally answered by a single google search.

Answer (score 1):

Before talking about the bandwidth of Bluetooth, let's learn about the technology behind Bluetooth. Bluetooth is an old technology for connecting two electronic devices without any wired connections. We can transfer the data packets from one device to another device with the use of radio waves. Every electronic device (which supports Bluetooth) consists of Bluetooth adapters, which are used for sending and receiving data. And we can only send the data packets only when the two devices are within the range(Bluetooth range) of each other. As the Bluetooth principal rule is to work on radio waves, we measure the frequency of Bluetooth on MHz, not on Mbps. The most common application of Bluetooth is: "Laptops, Headphones, Mobiles, printers and many more electronic devices...". Most of the electronic applications work on 2.4 GHz. The maximum range of Bluetooth is around 350m.

I think the above information might be a bit helpful for your research.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are mixing throughput with bandwidth:-

**Throughput** is the amount of data that can be sent per unit time. For this, the unit of measurement is bits per second (bps).

**Operating frequency** on the other hand is the frequency at which a wireless technology operates. The unit for this is Hz, and Bluetooth generally operates at 2400MHz - 2483MHz.

I recommend the links below to understand more the difference and how they are used programmatically:-

- [Classic Bluetooth vs Bluetooth Low Energy](https://www.semiconductorstore.com/blog/2014/Classic-Bluetooth-vs-Bluetooth-Low-Energy-A-Round-by-Round-Battle/860/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20dealing%20with,is%20the%20way%20to%20go.&text=The%20actual%20%2Fpractical%20transfer%20rate,2%20Mbps%20for%20Classic%20Bluetooth.)
- [Bluetooth 5 Speed: How to Achieve Maximum Throughput](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-speed-maximum-throughput/)
- [A Practical Guide to BLE Throughput](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/ble-throughput-primer)
- [The Difference between Classic Bluetooth and Bluetooth Low Energy](https://blog.nordicsemi.com/getconnected/the-difference-between-classic-bluetooth-and-bluetooth-low-energy)
- [Introduction to Bluetooth Classic](https://www.argenox.com/library/bluetooth-classic/introduction-to-bluetooth-classic/)
- [Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch01.html)
- [The Basics of Bluetooth Low Energy](https://www.novelbits.io/basics-bluetooth-low-energy/)